# remote: Empty password fatal: Authentication failed

Tags: windows, git, atlassian-sourcetree

After upgrading my SourceTree to 2.3.1.0 on my Windows 10 machine,

When I try to push my changes using SourceTree I get an error

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false push -v --tags origin master:master
remote: Empty password
```

fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://myusernameg@bitbucket.org/myusername/myrepositoryname.git/'
Pushing to https://myusername@bitbucket.org/myusername/myrepositoryname.git

I recall receiving this error and rolling back my SourceTree version to overcome it but I thought it should be fixed by now.

I also get the error if I try and re-clone the repository.

I upgraded SourceTree to the same version on my Windows 7 machine and I do not get the error there.

Comment: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/Can-t-push-using-sourcetree-since-last-update/qaq-p/629040#M17447

Comment: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/SourceTree-2-1-10-0-Authentication-Issues/qaq-p/623202#M19413

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tools->Options->Git-> Update Embedded Git.

I did have to do this twice because there were issues extracting the first down load.